# Error with the Iframe tag after upgrading to .NET 4.7.2

Tags: html, asp.net

I am upgrading my web projects to .NET 4.7.2 and I got an error with the Iframe tag.

At first I got the error:

> HttpParseException: The base class includes the field 'frame1', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe).

I made some change (added space) in the aspx file and saved it. It fixed this error. But then I got error inside the frame:

> The resource cannot be found.
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4667.0

I looked for a solution online, and made the following changes:
changed:

```
Protected WithEvents frame1 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.htmlIframe
```

to:

```
Protected WithEvents frame1 As Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe
```

changed:

```
<asp:TableCell> <IFRAME id="frame1"runat="server"> </IFRAME> </asp:TableCell>
```

to:

```
<asp:TableCell> <asp:htmlIframe id="frame1"runat="server"> </asp:htmlIframe> </asp:TableCell>
```

In config file, changed:

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

to:

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" assembly="System.Web"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

After all that, the error remained the same.

Did I understand the required changes correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error complains about the application code, not IFRAME. The error says that the type of the field, HtmlGenericControl, doesn't match the real control, HtmlIframe. Change your field's type to `HtmlIframe`. All other changes will only cause more errors

Comment: `HtmlIframe` isn't a new class, it exists [since .NET Framework 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmliframe?view=netframework-4.5). When you changed from `IFRAME` to `HtmlIframe` you changed the control type as well.

Comment: As for the 404, that means the IFrame points to an invalid URL. You didn't post the URL here so it's impossible to guess what's wrong

Comment: Why `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"`? Are you migrating from .NET Framework 3.5? That's a jump of 13 years. A *lot* has changed in that time. 4.0 introduced a lot of breaking changes in 2010, and 4.5 even more in 2012, even in WebForms.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I'm migrating from .NET FW 4.0. If I change the controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion to 4.0 or remove it, I get an error in a different location "Unable to get property 'submit' of undefined or null reference". Do you think the controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion is causes the problem?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.0 reached End-Of-Life 7 years ago, and even then, it seems it was an attempt to do the minimum to migrate what looks like .NET Framework 1.0 code with the minimum changes. I haven't seen `<IFRAME id="frame1" runat="server">` for a very long time. Instead of trying "solutions online" you should try to understand what that code does.  Back when .NET started, `<sometag ... runat="server">` was a way to access a tag without using the equivalent WebForms control.

Comment: The 404 means that the URL passed to the IFrame is wrong, not that the controls are wrong. As for the original errors, When `<sometag runat="server">` is used, the form field will be `HtmlGenericControl`, which offers no specialized methods. If you want to use that control in a more useful way you'd need to use a WebForms control, like `HtmlIframe`. It seems someone changed the field to `HtmlIframe` without also changing `<IFRAME...` to `<asp:HtmlIFrame>`.